Change the Catcode of the delimiter when define Macro
In the book TeX by Topic, Sec.2.8, Letters and other characters, there is a script to change Catcode in the <parameter text> when define a macro.
As it stated: because "the letters file resulting from the \jobname command have category code 12", in order to use the following command properly
\expandafter\getfilenumber\jobname.

the macro \getfilenumber is defined as:
{\escapechar=-1
\expandafter\gdef\expandafter\getfilenumber
\string\file#1.{\filenumber=#1 }
}

This changes the Catcode of the four characters f,i,l,e from 11 to 12 in the definition.
My question is: if the four characters f,i,l,e are  delimiters, e.g. they are placed after the #1, do we still have the way to change their Catcodes?
I tried:
{\escapechar=-1
\expandafter\gdef\expandafter\getfilenumberr\expandafter
#1\string\file.{\filenumber=#1 }
}

However, this does not work. We can compare \meaning with the original one:

The original one \meaning\getfilenumber gives
macro:file#1.->\filenumber =#1


And the trying code \meaning\getfilenumberr gives
macro:#1\string \file .->\filenumber =#1

Obviously,\string does not expand here.


#1 is two tokens not 1, so you need another \expandafter:

{\escapechar=-1
\expandafter\gdef\expandafter\getfilenumberr\expandafter
#\expandafter1\string\file.{\filenumber=#1 }
}
\show\getfilenumberr
\bye

producing
This is TeX, Version 3.141592653 (TeX Live 2024) (preloaded format=tex)
(./aa935.tex
> \getfilenumberr=macro:
#1file.->\filenumber =#1 .
l.6 \show\getfilenumberr
                        
?


It's a bit easier with engines other than classic tex that have \expanded (etex, pdftex, luatex, etc(

{\escapechar=-1
\expanded{\gdef\noexpand\getfilenumberr#1\string\file}.{\filenumber=#1 }
}
\show\getfilenumberr
\bye


This make sense and works. Thank you!

@XLeo I added a version with \expanded if you are not forced to use classic tex.

I am not. \expanded is much better! Avoid those crazy sets of \expandafter .

\let\getfilenumber\relax\expanded{\gdef\getfilenumber#1\detokenize{file.}}{#1} is even shorter

@egreg but shortness isn't everything, as you know, my code aims for elegance and beauty, I kept the \string form as it was in the question but probably I'd  do \expanded{\def\noexpand\getfilenumber#1\detokenize{file}}.{\filenumber=#1 } which is shorter still
